# OPA unit-test failing, How to output response variable?

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Newbie to OPA, I am writing OPA unit test case.

```
test_valid_type {
  response = evaluate with
             input as valid_type
  response == "approved"
}
```

it's failing `response == "approved"`. I want to see the output of response variable, how do i output it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `trace` method provided by OPA for debugging.
https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#debugging

This will let you print the output.
In your example you can add `trace(response)` which will print the response output.

Answer (score 0):

After reading many documention finally found it.

```
trace(variable)
```

prints the content of the variable.

```
[Ref][1]
```